# valueOf сравнение 2 обектов

Tags: javascript

Почему при сравнении 2 объектов (===) выдает **false**.

Но при других операциях(**>, <, +, -, *, /**) 2 объектов -  выдает нужный результат(то есть методы **valueOf** отрабатывают)

```
let man = {
    name: 'Sergey',
    surname: 'Sergeev',
    age: 30,
    valueOf(){
        return this.age;
    }
}


let man2 = {
    name: 'Ivan',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    age: 30,
    valueOf(){
        return this.age;
    }
}

console.log(man === man2)
```

Comment: Обьекты так сравнивать нельзя.

Comment: что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, можно

Comment: Вопрос не может быть дубликатом. Контекст вопросов разный. Особенно по первой ссылке. То есть, мне теперь получатся, если будут вопросы, связанные с преобразованием в JS — всех на эти ссылки слать (где речь про спецификацию) не давая конкретный ответ?

Comment: Тем более у человека принципиальный момент есть: в сравнение он использует метод `valueOf`, пусть и неявно в своем коде, в то время я бы рекомендовал использовать для этого просто сами свойства объектов `man.age` и `man2.age`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если вы хотите сравнивать возраст (да и вообще делать какие либо операции со значением свойств) — делайте это проще:**

```js
let man = {
  name: 'Sergey',
  surname: 'Sergeev',
  age: 30,
  valueOf() {
    return this.age;
  }
}


let man2 = {
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  age: 30,
  valueOf() {
    return this.age;
  }
}

console.log(man.age === man2.age);
```

**Ниже объяснение**

Метод valueOf() возвращает примитивное значение указанного объекта.

> JavaScript вызывает метод valueOf для преобразования объекта в
>   примитивное значение. Вам редко потребуется вызывать метод valueOf
>   самостоятельно; JavaScript автоматически вызывает его при обнаружении
>   объекта, **когда ожидается примитивное значение**.

Дело в том, что когда вы производите примитивные операции `>, <, +, -, *, /` с объектами в этом момент для каждого объекта возвращается приминивное значение каждого объекта — в вашем случае то, что вы переопределили в методах `valueOf`. И выволняются операции уже с возвращенными значениями.

Когда вы производите операции `==, ===` над объектами — сравниваются ссылки на объекты.

**Но если сделать так: когда один из операндов имеет примитивное значение — то объект тоже будет преобразовываться в к примитиву (когда не строгое ставнение):**

```js
let man = {
  name: 'Sergey',
  surname: 'Sergeev',
  age: 30,
  valueOf() {
    return this.age;
  }
}


let man2 = {
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  age: 30,
  valueOf() {
    return this.age;
  }
}

console.log(man === 30); // false, потому что сравниваются ссылки на объекты (=== — строгое сравнение)
console.log(man == 30); // true, потому что для man вернется примитивное значение
```

**Два «одинаковых» даже пустых объекта никогда не будут равны, потому что у объектов всегда будут сравниваться ссылки**

```js
console.log({} == {});
console.log({} === {});
```

**Но если сравниваются переменные, указывающие на один и тот же объект (имеют одну и ту же ссылку) — будет возвращаться `true`**

```js
var obj1 = {};
obj1.foo = 100;

var obj2 = obj1;
obj2.biz = 200;
obj1.bar = {
  text: 'bar'
};

console.log(obj1 == obj2);
console.log(obj1 === obj2);
```

**Дополнительная информация по преобразованию типов для примитивов и преобразованию объектов:**

- [Преобразование типов для примитивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion)
- [Преобразование объектов: toString и valueOf](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion)

Comment: Весь смысл в том, что операция == и === это не арифметическая операция, поэтому valueOf не отрабатывает. Но если == идет с примитивом, то объект начинает приводиться тоже к примитиву. при этом отрабатывет valueOf - я правильно понял?

Comment: @ruslik Чтобы прощё понять, когда вызывается `valueOf` у объекта —
 процитируют MDN _JavaScript автоматически вызывает его (`valueOf`) при обнаружении объекта, когда ожидается примитивное значение._ Например, `10 + obj`. Арифметическая операция? Да. Следовательно объект должен быть "преобразован" в приминивное значение — вызваться метод `valueOf`. Но если `valueOf` возвращает `true`? То будет происходить ещё одно преобразование: true станет 1 и в результате будет 11. В конец ответа добавил дополнительные ссылки — Илья Кантор в своём блоге прекрасно всё рассписал с примерами :)

Comment: @ruslik прекрасная документация у [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/) по JS и не только. Например, [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).Они себя так и позиционируют теперь (будут) как документация для разработчиков. В спецификацию мне пока не приходилось заглядывать — она всё-таки больше для разработчиков браузеров. В первую очередь смотрю информацию на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/), затем на [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/) или его [англ. вариант](http://javascript.info/) (улучшенный).

Comment: @ruslik важно разобраться с принципами, чтобы в любой ситуации понимать как себя «поведет» программа. Есть ещё нюансы с браузерами, но это другая история (не по valueOf, а вообще по разбору, интерпретации и выполнения JS в браузерных движках)...

Comment: Почему тогда [ ] == [ ], выдает false, ведь согласно документации, оба значение должны быть преобразовны к строке. -> получается "" == "", эта операция привет к численному преобразованию, получиться 0 == 0,   а это true. Почему тогда консоль выдает false

Comment: @ruslik потому что вы сравниваете объекты `[] == []`. И в текущем сравнении никаких преобразований не происходит, потому что сравниваются ссылки, и у каждого объекта они разные. Сравните `var a1 = []; var a2 = []; console.log([] == []); // false` и `var a1 = []; var a2 = a1; console.log(a1 == a2); // true`. «Преобразованы к строке» когда ожидается примитивный тип. А в такой конструкции — идет сравнение объекты с объектом (ссылок на объекты, если быть точным).

Comment: @ruslik Вот пример, когда ожидается примитивный тип `var a1 = [1, 2, 3]; console.log(a1 == '1,2,3'); // true`. Но если строгое сравнение `var a1 = [1, 2, 3]; console.log(a1 === '1,2,3'); // false`

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`===` не производит приведение типов и в случае **объектов** сравнивает **ссылки**. А `man` и `man2` это два разных объекта - они не могут быть строго равны.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, сравнивая эти два объекта с помощью операторов **(>, <, +, -, *, /)** вы получаете *численное преобразование*, т.к. операции для работы с числами. Поэтому вы получаете ожидаемый результат. По мимо этого, есть еще *логическое* и *строковое преобразование*. `===` используется для проверки равенства без преобразования типов, отсюда и два разных объекта будут разными. Либо используйте рекурсивное сравнение объектов, либо предпочтительнее - представьте объекты в виде строки и сравните их: `JSON.stringify(man1) === JSON.stringify(man2)`.

Comment: _JSON.stringify_ - применим не ко всем объектам